# cannot import name ProtocolBuffer

Tags: python, google-app-engine, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to debug app_engine project in visual studio 2015 .
So far I have these lines:

I installed with pip: endpoints, protopc, appengine and google-api-python-client libs

```
import endpoints
from protorpc import message_types
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import remote
```

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\users\someuser\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\froomPy\froomPy\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from protorpc import remote
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\protorpc\remote.py", line 117, in <module>
    from . import protobuf
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\protorpc\protobuf.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .google_imports import ProtocolBuffer
ImportError: cannot import name ProtocolBuffer
```

How can I handle this error `cannot import name ProtocolBuffer` or pip `google_imports`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are trying to run/debug this file, but I had the same problem when running:

```
python Hello_Endpoints/helloworld_api.py
```

...until I realized that I just had to run the .yaml function:

```
dev_appserver.py Hello_Endpoints/app.yaml
```

to start the server, and then go to http://localhost:8080/ to see the app running

Comment: This is fine unless you need to import `endpoints` in a standalone script. What is `.google_imports`?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue trying to run the tests in [this file](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/main_test.py) for the App Engine SDK echo API example.

Eventually I discovered this very helpful Google [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/localunittesting), titled "Local Unit Testing for Python". In particular, see the section titled "Setting up a testing framework".

It lists a number of specific (albeit tricky) changes required in order to run tests locally. With this article, I was able to get that test working. Here's what you need to do.

First, follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python). In particular, verify that when you reach the section "Running the sample locally", you can start the web server locally and that it responds correctly to the sample `curl` command. This ensures you have the App Engine SDK and the example set up correctly.

Next, run the following commands:

```
pip install pytest mock gcp-devrel-py-tools flaky protorpc
export GCLOUD_PROJECT=$(gcloud config get-value project)
```

Set the environment variable `ENDPOINTS_GAE_SDK` to point to your Google App Engine SDK directory, e.g. `/root/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine`.

Finally, run the tests:

```
py.test -v main_test.py
```

The tests should now run successfully, printing something like:

```
========================================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.13, pytest-3.5.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /usr/local/pyenv/versions/2.7.13/bin/python2.7
cachedir: ../../../../.pytest_cache
rootdir: /opt/root/src/python-docs-samples, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: cov-2.5.1, hypothesis-3.56.10, flaky-3.4.0
collected 2 items

main_test.py::test_echo PASSED                                                                                                                                                                     [ 50%]
main_test.py::test_get_user_email PASSED                                                                                                                                                           [100%]

======================================================================================== 2 passed in 2.24 seconds ========================================================================================
```

Here is the source code for the working version of the test. (I'm sure this could be cleaner...)

```
# Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

import os
import sys


def fixup_paths(path):
    try:
        import google
        google.__path__.append("{0}/google".format(path))
    except ImportError:
        pass

    sys.path.insert(0, path)


fixup_paths(os.getenv('ENDPOINTS_GAE_SDK'))

import dev_appserver
dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()

try:
    import appengine_config
    (appengine_config)
except ImportError:
    print('Note: unable to import appengine_config.')


sys.path.append(os.path.expandvars('$ENDPOINTS_GAE_SDK'))
sys.path.append(os.path.expandvars('$ENDPOINTS_GAE_SDK/lib/yaml/lib'))
sys.path.append('lib')

from google.appengine.ext import testbed

import endpoints
import mock
import pytest
from protorpc import message_types

import main


@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def gae_testbed(request):
    tb = testbed.Testbed()
    tb.activate()

    def deactivate():
        tb.deactivate()

    request.addfinalizer(deactivate)


def test_echo(gae_testbed):
    api = main.EchoApi()
    request = main.EchoApi.echo.remote.request_type(content='Hello world!')
    response = api.echo(request)
    assert 'Hello world!' == response.content


def test_get_user_email(gae_testbed):
    api = main.EchoApi()

    with mock.patch('main.endpoints.get_current_user') as user_mock:
        user_mock.return_value = None
        with pytest.raises(endpoints.UnauthorizedException):
            api.get_user_email(message_types.VoidMessage())

        user_mock.return_value = mock.Mock()
        user_mock.return_value.email.return_value = 'user@example.com'
        response = api.get_user_email(message_types.VoidMessage())
        assert 'user@example.com' == response.content
```